# Draw Android screen overlay off the screen borders

Tags: android, overlay

I have implemented an Android application overlay that's basically a floating view on the screen. The view actually works fine and the user can drag it freely on the screen. See the following screenshot and snippet:

[image: screenshot]

```
WindowManager windowManager = (WindowManager) context.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
WindowManager.LayoutParams params = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
        WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
        WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
        WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_APPLICATION_OVERLAY,
        WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE,
        PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);
View screenOverlay = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.screenOverlay, null);
windowManager.addView(screenOverlay, params);
```

I added this simple pulse animation behind the overlay -> https://lottiefiles.com/animations/pulse-circle-UnqpwHUUQT

The problem arises here. I need to show the animation while the overlay is at the edge of the screen, so that the animation will partly grow outside the borders of the screen. Please check the following screenshots to see what I want to achieve:

[image]

And this is my initial layout file for the content of overlay:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:clipToPadding="false"
        android:clipChildren="false"
        android:padding="0dp">

    <View
            android:layout_width="80dp"
            android:layout_height="80dp"
            android:background="@drawable/animation_background" />

    <View
            android:layout_width="48dp"
            android:layout_height="48dp"
            android:background="@drawable/content_background"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

However, I couldn't manage to draw the animation outside the screen. The inner content has 48dp width, and the animation has 80dp width. There are several methods I tried but they probably do not work for application overlay:

- Setting margin of the container to something negative had no effect on application overlay.
- Setting container width to explicitly 48dp, using `clipToPadding` and `clipChildren` attributes to be false together was another suggested solution. But this is causing the animation already to appear clipped from all sides.
- Programmatically setting the position or margins of the overlay does not work. I cannot simply move it off the screen boundaries.

I assume that drawing/moving an overlay view outside the screen borders is not possible. I have not found a solid proof checking through the Android documentation and questions here, but it seems to behave that way. If you have any suggestions to achieve this, or any proof that doing this is not possible, it would be appreciated!

Comment: "I assume that drawing/moving an overlay view outside the screen borders is not possible" -- by "screen borders", do you mean "window borders"?

Comment: @CommonsWare Yes I mean window borders